# How can I have a Bootstrap button in the disabled state when the page loads?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want a bootstrap button to be disabled when the page loads. I know that I could just toggle it into the disabled state programmatically via `$().button('loading')` but then there will be a brief period of time while rendering that the button isn't disabled. How can I have it render disabled by default?

When disabled, bootstraps buttons have a disabled class and attribute.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary disabled" disabled="disabled" data-loading-text="Loading...">Click Me</button>
```

I can add that additional class and attribute, but I still the problem of how to tell bootstrap what the normal state and disabled texts are. If I have it disabled when the page loads, I need a `data-normal-text` attribute but there doesn't appear to be something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, but I would imagine you could do something like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary disabled" disabled="disabled">
  Loading...
</button>
```

It's disabled, now when you are ready you can:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('button.disabled[disabled=disabled]')
    .removeClass('disabled')
    .prop('disabled', false)
    .text('Click Me');
});
```

I haven't used the `button()` method so bare with the answer.  This isn't exactly 100% optimal from the UI/UX point of view, but functionally it should be 100% and still have very good user experience.

Comment: You nailed it.   There's no HTML-attribute method to change text on a button in the current version of Bootstrap.  Jquery it is.

Comment: This would be correct if you removed `.button('loading')` because that action enables the disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to define your own text via DOM attributes. Quoting from the [Bootstrap Button docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-stateful):

> **Use whichever state you like!**
>
> For the sake of this demonstration, we are using `data-loading-text` and `$().button('loading')`, but that's
>   not the only state you can use. See more on this below in the
>   `$().button(string)` documentation.

So I can add a `data-ready-text="Click Me"` and toggle it with `$().button('ready')`. However, that doesn't remove the disabled state of the button; I still have to do that myself.

It's worth noting that the loading state is a special one that disables the button. There is no way to tell Bootstrap that you want your custom state to also disable the button. Again, you have to do that manually.